# A problem about dense set

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Is $\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{I}$ dense set in $\mathbb{R}$?

**My approach:**  I think the answer is **yes**, since that if $D\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and $D$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and $D\subseteq A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ so $A$ is dense set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Then, since $\mathbb{I}$ is dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{I}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{I}$ so  using the before fact, we have that $\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{I}$ is dense set in $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Is my proof correct?
Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Thank you. Any suggestion?

Comment: If $\Bbb I\subseteq\Bbb Q+\Bbb I$ and $\Bbb Q\subseteq\Bbb Q+\Bbb I$ then $\Bbb Q\cup\Bbb I=\Bbb R\subseteq\Bbb Q+\Bbb I\subseteq\Bbb R$, so $\Bbb Q+\Bbb I$ is in fact $\Bbb R$

Comment: @Darsen why can you suppose that hypothesis? Is $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{I}$?

Comment: @Darsen Surely $\mathbb{Q}+\mathbb{I}=\mathbb{I}$

Comment: So $\Bbb Q+\Bbb I$ isn't closed under addition?

Comment: @Darsen $0$ is not in $\mathbb Q + \mathbb I$, it is not $\mathbb R$. And no, it's not closed under addition, since is equal to $\mathbb I$ as epiliam noted.

Comment: Apparently everyone here understand the notation $\mathbb{I}$, but I don't... Could you precise what its is ?

Comment: Set of irrational numbers.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe $\mathbb{I}$=set of irrational numbers.